# Send file to remote device with bluetooth without the requirement of a pin using obexftp in terminal

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, obex, obexftp

Hi This command in terminal

```
obexftp –nopath –noconn –uuid none –bluetooth <BTAddr> –channel <OPUSHChannelNo> –put <FileToPut>
```

Should allow a file to be sent to remote bluetooth device without the requirement of a pin on a remote device.

When i populate this with my data

```
obexftp –nopath –noconn –uuid none –bluetooth 64:89:9A:DE:49:FA –channel 12 –put DUN.jpg
```

I get the following error

> Try `obexftp --help' for more information.
>   Nothing to do. Use --help for help.

I can get it to work with this terminal command

```
obexftp --nopath -noconn --uuid none --bluetooth 64:89:9A:DE:49:FA --channel 12 -put DUN.jpg
```

But the problem is the remote device asks the user to pair before allowing the file to be received. I need the solution to skip the pair request.

Or if anyone can suggest an alternative terminal solution where i can send a file from a raspberry pi to mobile device without the requirement to pair would be great.

Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Even i am facing these issue. No matter how u use the obexftp with bluez, you need to use the pin to pair the device which was not acceptable by me.

Though there is one way around, use gnome-bluetooth package, you will be able to send the file using bluetooth-sento command with some parameters which i guess you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently been attempting something similar using an embedded device and an Android phone.  I believe what you are seeking is not possible as it would be a security risk for the Android device is you could just simply push a file to the Android device without first asking for permission/pairing.  Unless you make modifications to the Android device and underlying code, I do not think you will be able to achieve your desired goal.